# What is the function of 0x0700 in cga_putc?

Tags: c, console, operating-system, printf

I am studying for [Operating System Engineering](https://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2011/schedule.html) recently, and I found a "magic number" that I can't figure out in the `kern/console.c` when I tried to read the source code.

Basically, `static void cga_putc(int c)` in [`kern/console.c`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Jameeeees/MIT-JOS/master/lab1/kern/console.c) is a function for output the character to the console, it is used by `cprintf` in this kernel.

```
static void cga_putc(int c)
{
    // if no attribute given, then use black on white
    if (!(c & ~0xFF))
        c |= 0x0700;

    switch (c & 0xff) {
    case '\b':
        ...
    case '\n':
        ...
    default:
        crt_buf[crt_pos++] = c;     /* write the character */
        break;
    }
    ...
}
```

However, I don't understand the function of `if (!(c & ~0xFF)) c |= 0x0700;`, can anybody help me with this? I don't know which material I should look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read it through.

> ~0xFF: invert 0xFF, i.e 0xFFFFFF00 if using a 32 bit number
>
> c & 0xffffff00: look at the high order bits
>
> if (!c): if no high order bits, set the high order bits to 0x0700;

The purpose of this is pretty much explained in the preceding comment:

> // if no attribute given, then use black on white

Highly likely that the high order bits are controlling the FG and BG color of the text.